# Docker Commit Usage

Tags: docker

I'm interested in using docker to encapsulate an entire application with persistent state changed by users. It has a web-app, which accesses both a database in the docker container and the file-system of the docker container.

I saw elsewhere online that you can use `docker commit` to save changes to a running container back to an image. This seems like what I want, but I want to make sure. The idea would be that once a user logs into the web-app (hosted from the docker container) and makes some changes, they would then `docker commit` those changes. If this happens frequently, does this drastically increase the size of their docker image or does the image only store the latest state? Are there any gotchas here I should worry about?

If so, what alternatives should I consider?

Thanks in advance,
Jack

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend avoiding `docker commit` for a lot of other reasons:

1. Your web-server will be unavailable - can you afford that? from [docs](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/commit/#extended-description):

> By default, the container being committed and its processes will be
> paused while the image is committed.

2. It's hard to reproduce. How will you know what's happened in the last commit? and one before? if you ever need to revert, do you want to lose all your data?

I would recommend using docker `volumes` for storage persistency and your database can run on another separate container.

**UPDATE**:

For saving your MariaDB data, as [docs](https://hub.docker.com/_/mariadb) say you need to mount the `/var/lib/mysql` to wherever you like in your host machine,
for example:

```
docker run -v /my/own/datadir:/var/lib/mysql -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=my-secret-pw -d mariadb:<relevant_tag>
```

that way your database will always use your `/my/own/datadir` in localhost - you just need to make sure that you are not going to delete this folder and that's it.

Comment: Even if I run the database in another container, don't I still have the same issue in THAT container? (For that container, do I also use Volumes for persisting the database storage?)

Comment: most of the databases use VOLUME in their Dockerfile to ensure your data is still available after stop/start (also depends on your orchestrator). Which database you are using?

Comment: I'm using MariaDB.

Comment: @JacKeown I've updated the answer for you

Answer (score 1):

`docker commit` is almost never a best practice.  Ignore it in the Docker documentation, and forget it exists entirely.

In the use case you're describing where a user logs into the application, the application's data should be maintained separately from the application proper.  Ideally you can store the application data in a database or some other fully external storage, in a separate container or outside Docker entirely.  If you can't, then using a Docker [volume](https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/) will allow the application's data to be persisted even if the container is deleted and recreated.

If you have some change in your application proper, then the correct approach is to make the change in your image's Dockerfile, re-run `docker build`, and then create a new container with the new image.  Most continuous-integration systems can be configured to build new Docker images whenever the application's source changes.

These two practices can be combined.  If the data is stored externally from the container, and there is an update to the application image, you can delete the old container and start a new container with the new image and the same data (from an external database or a mounted volume).  Deleting containers this way is extremely routine.

There are a number of practical problems with `docker commit`.  The biggest one is that changes aren't tracked anywhere and can't be replayed: if there's a critical security update in your original base image, you can't recreate a committed image without executing the same manual steps again.  In the workflow you describe you'd have to somehow export the data from the image, start from the updated base image, copy the data back in, and commit the image again; that's a lot of steps to remember to do perfectly every time.  Each commit also unconditionally makes the image bigger (even if data was deleted), and there may be a limit on the number of times you can commit an image (historically there was a limit of 127 layers).